# How do I sort this scatter plot?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to sort this scatter plot, which is summarized with a Band that includes Minimum, Average, and Maximum.

I would like to sort it in 2 ways:

- by Average
- by Widest Range (ie difference between Minimum and Maximum values)

[Tableau Public workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/kane.see#!/vizhome/CVSS_15537984621910/boxCvss?publish=yes)
If you can't view this or I'm not allowed to post external resources on stackoverflow, then perhaps you can show me on this screenshot what I would click to get started on the following sort
[image]

Also, bonus question, is there a way to create a control for the user to toggle between the 2 sort methods in the same chart? Or do I have to duplicate the chart with a different sort type for each?

One note is that I only have Tableau Public version since I'm evaluating the product. Until I get a paid version, I can't open a workbook file unless you publish it to Tableau Public cloud. But rather than give me the workbook answer, I would just appreciate it if you gave me instructions to do this as this is more of a learning exercise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat unfortunately, you'll have to replicate the min,avg,max by creating 3 calculated fields. Tableau cannot operate on the values placed on the view via reference lines.

These calculations might look something like these:

```
{Fixed [Cwe]: Min([Cvss Score])}
```

~

```
{Fixed [Cwe]: Avg([Cvss Score])}
```

~

```
{Fixed [Cwe]: Max([Cvss Score])}
```

In general, from there, you should pretty easily be able to apply them to the view and sort. Average will be easy. The difference between Min and Max will just need a subtracting calculated field to sort by. Once they're on the view, I'd put them as a dimension (column) to verify that the numbers look correct.

Take note that LOD calculations take place before filtering, so you'll want to put the Cvss filter you have there 'on context' by right clicking it and clicking 'add to context'

Here is how I would complete the sorts:

Starting with all the above calculations on 'Rows' and ensuring that they are 'Dimensions' (Blue). 
[image]

After right clicking "Sort..." on [Sub-Category] on 'Rows'. Select which field to sort by.

[image]

From there, the calculated fields can be taken off the rows column. (They were only there in the first place to ensure that you could check that the sorts took place. They don't actually need to have been there in the first place.)

Comment: I'm very new to Tableau. Where in the view do i drag them to (without affecting my existing chart)? Maybe you can show me a screenshot or describe which panel I should drag them to

Comment: Edited answer to hopefully show how to go about the sorts with some pictures from the sample SuperStore dataset.

Comment: Thanks! This gets me close enough to what I want and I can take it from here. Quick note, I think you left out a bracket e.g. {Fixed [Cwe]: Min([Cvss Score])}